# How to boot always manaually from grub> minimal-bash

Tags: grub2

I'm New Here, I've been using Linux For More Than 2 Years and Every Day I learn a lot about Linux , My Question Is That How To Disable or prevent Grub from Showing The Menu Entry , I want to always boot manually from grub> Minimal Bash 
how i can do this ?

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete your grub.cfg and prevent it from being auto generated again:

```
sudo rm /boot/grub/grub.cfg
sudo chmod a-x /etc/grub.d/*
```

Comment: but , when i do
ls
it shows me this result
(hd0) (hd0,msdos1) hd0,msdos2) (hd0,msdos3)

now i have executed 
ls (hd0,msdos1)/
and it appears the root file system
can i understand that root file system in /dev/sda1 ??

Comment: @AhmedAbdul-Monem, if that's what it looks like, then that's probably what it is.  You may want to set root=(hd0,1)/.